# How to disallow access to all dot directories except .well-known?

Tags: nginx

I've got this in my nginx config:

```
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location /.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}
```

But I still can't access `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/taUUGC822PcdnCnW_aADOzObZqFm3NNM5PEzLNFJXRU`. How do I allow access to just that one dot directory?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have a regex location and a prefix location. The regex location takes precedence unless `^~` is used with the prefix location. Try:

```
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
location ^~ /.well-known/ {
#   allow all;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Should be `/\.well_known/` then, shouldn't it? Isn't `^~` a regex?

Comment: No it isn't a regex. **But**, if you *did* want to change it to a regex, you would also need to place it *above* the more general regex, as regex locations are ordered.

Comment: Oh it isn't? The docs are very unclear about what each of the symbols do. Thanks for clarifying. You've commented out `allow all` -- that's because of this rule, right? "If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked."

Comment: Wait.. if `^~` is not a regex, then it's just a starts-with-case-sensitive match, right? What's no symbol do then? Is that a "contains" search, or also a starts with search?

Comment: I commented it out because `allow all` should be the default, and to emphasise that this isn't Apache and locations do not merge. `nginx` chooses one location to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).

Comment: No symbol means *prefix location* (or what you call starts-with-case-sensitive match) but has a lower precedence than regex. `^~` is a *prefix location* with a higher precedence than regex.

Comment: I would like to note for anyone seeing this since it appears near the top of Google results that (for me at least) it uses a - (dash) and not a _ (underscore).

Answer (score 16):

I would go with an optimised code:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
```

So that all dots are denied except .well-known folder

Comment: The [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) say *"If the longest matching prefix location has the ^~ modifier then regular expressions are not checked."* So although this is a simpler and more understandable solution, it is not optimised, but the accepted answer is. This is a good alternative, as long as you remove the word "optimised" which is misleading, as it's a simpler solution so people will use it incorrectly.